# How can I authenticate user in Play's 2.0 WebSocket?

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

ellou'

I have common Play WebSocket method which is working as expected, but I need to authenticate user. Unfortunately when trying even simplest way to identify user in the method:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static WebSocket<JsonNode> connect() {
        return new WebSocket<JsonNode>() {

            @Override
            public void onReady(final WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, final WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out) {
                User logged = User.findByUsername(Http.Context.current().request().username());
                // ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
```

My current workaround is to pass random, unique identifier to view and saving it in User model, than I can connect to the socket from the view and find user with the given identifier, but this is no perfect as there can be only one WebSocket connection per user and also doesn't prevent the spoof.

How should I authenticate the user and prevent spoof attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As data I want to send are sensitive and in this case security is more important to me than performance, finally I used two-step messages, first sending via WebSocket id of the message and some not important data and then fetching via AJAX and secured action message body after user's authentication.

**Question remains opened:** Of course if there will be other suggestions I will change my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where comes your piece of code, but you should be able to access the HTTP request  on the initialization of the Websocket (first connection), ie you should be able to check for authentication only when you initiate the websocket socket connection (subsequent call will not be using HTTP, it is how Webscokets works).

So for instance, in your controller, you could have something like this:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

   public static WebSocket<JsonNode> connect() {

        Logger.info("Username from request = " + request().username());

        return new WebSocket<JsonNode>() {

            @Override
            public void onReady(final WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, final WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out) {
                // ....

            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I edited my sample, to fit your code, as you can see I placed it in `onReady(...)`, it returns the exception, when placed before `return` it returns null. Of course both lines (your `request().username()` and my `Http.Context.current()...`) returns valid username in common action.

Comment: Don't you have any kind of annotation on common actions ? How are you setting the username ?

Comment: Both actions are in the same controller, annotation for the Secured.class is included to the controller, not to action so both should use them the same way. I think the problem is that common action gets Http.Context and WebSocket is not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried retrieving the authenticated user ID from the HTTP Session instead? The context seems to be available at that point.